# How do I convert a list of chars into a list of strings in F#?

Tags: list, f#, f#-interactive

I have a list of chars that looks like this ['a'; 'b'; '&'; 'c']. I now want to convert this into a list of strings ["a"; "b"; "&"; "c"] and not one string "ab&c" since in the end, I want to compare two lists with strings. How do I go from a list of characters to a list of strings? Thanks a lot for the help

```
let varL1 = ['a';'b';'&';'c']

let rec ConvertToString list =
   match list with
   | [l] -> l.ToString()
   | head :: tail -> head.ToString() + "," + ConvertToString tail
   | [] -> ""

ConvertToString varL1
```

I tried the code abovce but his gives me "ab&c" which is not what I am looking for. I am looking for ["a";"b";"&";"c"]

Comment: As a hint, use the [`::` (cons) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/lists#operators-for-working-with-lists) to build up the result list, instead of concatenating strings with `+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let varL1 = ['a'; 'b'; '&'; 'c']

let rec ConvertToString list =
    match list with
    | head :: tail -> string head :: ConvertToString tail
    | [] -> []

let varL2 = ConvertToString varL1
```

Try this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you want to transform a list of `'a` into a list of `'b`, the `List.map` function is the most straight forward:

```ml
let listOfChars = ['a';'b';'&';'c']
let listOfStrings = 
  listOfChars 
  |> List.map string
```

The `List.map` function expects a function from `'a` to `'b` (`'a -> 'b`), and a list of `'a`, and returns list of `'b`: full signature being `('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list`.

In the code above, I pass the `string` function, which converts the input (a char in this particular case) to a string.

https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-listmodule.html#map
https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-operators.html#string